# Error on opening popviewcontroller in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

It looks a simple thing to me but I am not able to understand what mistake I am making. I have to open a popover on click of row in my iPad application. I have done following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    popViewController *vc = [[popViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"popViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,500);
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);

    UIPopoverController *healthPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [healthPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

The app crashes when last line is executed. I have searched lots of pages on the web, but I am not able to find its cause. I am not getting any specific error only the Thread 1 error in the main file.

I am using iOS 7.

Comment: The problem is with not retaining the popover. Retain the popover as suggested by @null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your healthPopOverit a member of your class since `UIPopoverControllers` must be held in an instance variable.

In your .m define it as a property:

```
UIPopoverController *healthPopOver;
```

and change:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    popViewController *vc = [[popViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"popViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,500);
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);

    self.healthPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [healthPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked... Though it sounds quite weird to me. Do you know the reason why it does so?

Comment: @pankaj I guess you must using ARC. So your local variable `healthPopOver` will be released by ARC after `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` function ended. Cash may occurs on this point.

Comment: `UIPopoverController` doesn't have a superview, and it deosn't get retained by anybody unless you don't retain it, so by doing `UIPopoverController *healthPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] init ...` the variable becomes out of scope and the object gets deallocated since it has no owner anymore, this is why you need to retain it.